# How to import Datadog JSON template in terraform DSL?

Tags: terraform, datadog

```
{
   "title":"xxxx",
   "description":"xxx",
   "widgets":[
      {
         "id":0,
         "definition":{
            "type":"timeseries",
            "requests":[
               {
                  "q":"xxxxxx{xxxx:xx}",
                  "display_type":"bars",
                  "style":{
                     "palette":"cool",
                     "line_type":"solid",
                     "line_width":"normal"
                  }
               }
           ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have the above datadog json template with me which I have to just import in terraform instead of recreating it as terraform dsl.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include any Terraform code that you've tried so far?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR this is the actual converted version
https://github.com/prashanth-sams/datadog-automation-dashboard-terraform/blob/master/modules/default/dashboard.tf

Comment: Then I'm not sure I understand your question. What's wrong with the version you linked to?

Comment: What I have in the github link works fine but my manager dont want to have it like a templated version; he said what I use is the resource and not modules. He said it should be like a class

Comment: Thats why I thought of keeping everything in a json file and just import it in tf file

Comment: Would be great if you give me some sugesstions or improvements that I can optimize

Comment: You could maybe mangle something using the [JSON syntax](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/syntax-json.html) but it won't be a 1 to 1 import so will need a lot of wrangling to get it right. Or you could generate the HCL from the JSON I guess. Or raise a pull request to the datadog provider to have it optionally accept the definition of the dashboard as a JSON blob like the [`aws_cloudwatch_dashboard` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudwatch_dashboard.html).

Comment: Perhaps this helps https://github.com/laurmurclar/datadog-to-terraform

Answer (score 1):

I'm not particularly familiar with this Datadog JSON format but the general pattern I would propose here has multiple steps:

- Decode the serialized data into a normal Terraform value. In this case that would be using [`jsondecode`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/jsondecode.html), because the data is JSON-serialized.
- Transform and normalize that raw data into a consistent shape that is more convenient to use in a declarative Terraform configuration. This will usually involve at least one [named local value](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/locals.html) containing an expression that uses [`for` expressions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#for-expressions) and [the `try` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/try.html), along with the type conversion functions, to try to force the raw data into a more consistent shape.
- Use the transformed/normalized result with Terraform's resource and block repetition constructs (resource `for_each` and `dynamic` blocks) to describe how the data maps onto physical resource types.

Here's a basic example of that to show the general principle. It will need more work to capture all of the details you included in your initial example.

```
variable "datadog_json" {
  type = string
}

locals {
  raw = jsondecode(var.datadog_json)
  screenboard = {
    title       = local.raw.title
    description = try(local.raw.description, tostring(null))
    widgets = [
      for w in local.raw.widgets : {
        type   = w.definition.type

        title       = w.definition.title
        title_size  = try(w.definition.title_size, 16)
        title_align = try(w.definition.title_align, "center")

        x      = try(w.definition.x, tonumber(null))
        y      = try(w.definition.y, tonumber(null))
        width  = try(w.definition.x, tonumber(null))
        height = try(w.definition.y, tonumber(null))

        requests = [
          for r in w.definition.requests : {
            q            = r.q
            display_type = r.display_type
            style        = tomap(try(r.style, {}))
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

resource "datadog_screenboard" "acceptance_test" {
  title       = local.screenboard.title
  description = local.screenboard.description
  read_only   = true

  dynamic "widget" {
    for_each = local.screenboard.widgets
    content {
      type = widget.value.type

      title       = widget.value.title
      title_size  = widget.value.title_size
      title_align = widget.value.title_align

      x      = widget.value.x
      y      = widget.value.y
      width  = widget.value.width
      height = widget.value.height

      tile_def {
        viz = widget.value.type

        dynamic "request" {
          for_each = widget.value.requests
          content {
            q            = request.value.q
            display_type = request.value.display_type
            style        = request.value.style
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The separate normalization step to build `local.screenboard` here isn't strictly necessary: you could instead put the same sort of normalization expressions (using `try` to set defaults for things that aren't set) directly inside the `resource "datadog_screenboard"` block arguments if you wanted. I prefer to treat normalization as a separate step because then this leaves a clear definition in the configuration for what we're expecting to find in the JSON and what default values we'll use for optional items, separate from defining how that result is then mapped onto the physical `datadog_screenboard` resource.

I wasn't able to test the example above because I don't have a Datadog account. I'm sorry if there are minor typos/mistakes in it that lead to errors. My hope was to show the general principle of mapping from a serialized data file to a resource rather than to give a ready-to-use solution, so I hope the above includes enough examples of different situations that you can see how to extend it for the remaining Datadog JSON features you want to support in this module.

---

If this JSON format is a interchange format formally documented by Datadog, it could make sense for Terraform's Datadog provider to have the option of accepting a single JSON string in this format as configuration, for easier exporting. That may require changes to the Datadog provider itself, which is beyond what I can answer here but might be worth raising in the GitHub issues for that provider to streamline this use-case.

Comment: sounds interesting; let me give a try